# SQL Query for CHI-SQUARE TEST gives Wrong Result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, chi-squared

Please help me as I have been trying to find out the CHI-SQUARED Test using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Developers Edition. The problem is that the query works fine on the following set of sample data:

```
sessionnumber   sessioncount    timespent          cnt
    1                  17               28          45
    2                  22               8           30
    3                  1                1           2
    4                  1                1           2
    5                  8               111          119
    6                  8                65          73
    7                  11               5           16
    8                  1                1           2
    9                  62               64          126
   10                  6                42          48
```

so, the query I have been trying is:

```
SELECT sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent, expected, dev,
dev*dev/cast(expected as float) as chi_square

FROM (SELECT d3.sessionnumber, d3.sessioncount, d3.timespent,
(dim1.cnt * dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/cast((dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt)as float) as expected,
d3.cnt-(dim1.cnt * dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/(dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt) as dev FROM d3 JOIN

(SELECT sessionnumber, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt FROM d3
GROUP BY sessionnumber) dim1
ON d3.sessionnumber = dim1.sessionnumber JOIN

(SELECT sessioncount, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt FROM d3
GROUP BY sessioncount) dim2
ON d3.sessioncount = dim2.sessioncount JOIN

(SELECT timespent, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt FROM d3
GROUP BY timespent) dim3
ON d3.timespent = dim3.timespent CROSS JOIN

(SELECT SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt FROM d3) dimall) a
```

The Result generating by this Query is wrong and the result is:

```
sessionnumber   sessioncount    timespent          expected                              dev            chi_square
    1                  17               28          2.37921034130308E-09        44.9999999976208    851122729517.387
    2                  22               8           1.72099699796333E-10        29.9999999998279    5229526844351.02
    3                  1                1           1.3008335197251E-11         1.99999999998699    307495151323.689
    4                  1                1           1.3008335197251E-11         1.99999999998699    307495151323.689
    5                  8               111          1.90995107994937E-07        118.999999809005    74143260019.6156
    6                  8                65          5.09110109296227E-09        72.9999999949089    1046728379961.52
    7                  11               5           5.36406353430159E-11        15.9999999999464    4772501264409.71
    8                  1                1           1.3008335197251E-11         1.99999999998699    307495151323.689
    9                  62               64          6.56781317803123E-09        125.999999993432    2417242934291.85
   10                  6                42          1.41737398829092E-09        47.9999999985826    1625541331291.19
```

As a correct Chi Square test for the sessionnumber 1 and sessionnumber 2 should be equal to 9.117 as my Query is giving me the wrong Result. (this chi square is a sample but correct value for the first 2 sessionnumbers rows).
So I have been trying to get the answer and working since last 3 days. Lastly found my this query with problems and it gives me wrong results.

Please somebody help me I will be helpful for this help! (I will apply bounty after 2 days on this question also).
Thanks in advance Please help me as I have a little knowledge about SQL Queries because I am very new to it lols using since about 3 months only! SO I NEED SOME HELP REALLY!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query for Chi-SQUARE TEST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043311/sql-query-for-chi-square-test)

Comment: That question has less information @Gidil

Comment: What results do you want to achieve? If you give an example of how to calculate that (not using SQL) it will be easier to help.

Comment: Are you sure that query actually runs?  I see some ambiguous fields in your select clause.

Comment: @ricardo please open this link http://psychology.ucdavis.edu/sommerb/sommerdemo/stat_inf/tutorials/chisqhand.htm

Comment: Why are you doing statistics using SQL?

Comment: so can you please give me any other soulution?

Answer (score 3):

The chi-square value is defined on a 2 dimensions contingency table, not on a 3-dimensional contingency table.  You seem to be adapting the 2-dimensional formula to three dimensions.  And, they just don't work.

You *can* generalize the chi-square to higher dimensionality tests.  I discuss this in this [blog](http://blog.data-miners.com/2008/12/multidimensional-chi-square-expected.html) posting, along with reasons why I counsel against this approach.

I would suggest you rephrase the problem as a 2-dimensional chi-square test and apply the arithmetic in your code to this problem.  That is, do the analysis two dimensions at a time.

EDIT:

I don't think you understand the Chi-Square Test.  It is applied when you have two dimensions of *categorical* variables.  For instance, you might have "color" and "response" and a matrix that has:

```
Color     Yes     No
Red        18    203
Blue       10    182
Green      22    134
```

And you want to know the probability (likelihood) that the matrix is created at random -- assuming the distribution of marginals (the totals on the dimensions) is the same.

Your example has two or three (if you include "sessionnumber") numeric variables.  You should be looking at alternative statistical techniques.  I would actually start with single-variate correlation analysis (Pearson correlation) and a linear regression.

EDIT II:

I am providing the correct form for the Chi-Square query, even though I don't advocate using the Chi-Square test on your data.  The columns are, presumably, related (instances with high session count would seem to be similar even if they are not in the same bucket).

Your query had the right form, just remove one of the dimensions:

```
SELECT sessioncount, timespent, expected, dev,
       dev*dev/cast(expected as float) as chi_square
FROM (SELECT d3.sessionnumber, d3.sessioncount, d3.timespent,
             (dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/cast((dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt)as float) as expected,
             d3.cnt-(dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/(dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt) as dev
      FROM d3 JOIN
           (SELECT sessioncount, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY sessioncount
           ) dim2
           ON d3.sessioncount = dim2.sessioncount JOIN
           (SELECT timespent, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY timespent
           ) dim3
           ON d3.timespent = dim3.timespent CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
          ) dimall
     ) a
```

That works for the cells that you have in the table.  However, to get the full Chi-Square value, you need to account for all cells, even those with counts of 0:

```
SELECT sessioncount, timespent, cnt, expected, dev,
       dev*dev/cast(expected as float) as chi_square
FROM (SELECT allcells.sessioncount, allcells.timespent,
             cells.cnt,
             (dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/cast(dimall.cnt as float) as expected,
             coalesce(cells.cnt, 0) - (dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/dimall.cnt as dev
      FROM (select sc.sessioncount, ts.timespent
            from (select distinct sessioncount from d3) sc cross join
                 (select distinct timespent from d3) ts
           ) allcells left join
           (select sessioncount, timespent, sum(cnt) as cnt
            from d3
            group by sessioncount, timespent
           ) cells
           on allcells.sessioncount = cells.sessioncount and
              allcells.timespent = cells.timespent left JOIN
           (SELECT sessioncount, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY sessioncount
           ) dim2
           ON allcells.sessioncount = dim2.sessioncount left JOIN
           (SELECT timespent, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY timespent
           ) dim3
           ON allcells.timespent = dim3.timespent CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
          ) dimall
     ) a
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f64/17) is a SQL Fiddle that has this working.

And, your original query probably would work for a multi-dimensional chi-square.  However, I had not looked closely enough at the data.  Normally when data has a cnt, it is in the form of a contingency table (perhaps with "0" cells missing).  Your data has cells split across multiple rows (notably "1, 1").  So, the above version takes that into account.

And, because your original question was about a 3-dimensional Chi-Square, here is the correct query for that:

```
SELECT sessioncount, timespent, cnt, expected, dev,
       dev*dev/cast(expected as float) as chi_square
FROM (SELECT allcells.sessionnumber, allcells.sessioncount, allcells.timespent,
             cells.cnt,
             (dim1.cnt * dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/cast(dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt as float) as expected,
             coalesce(cells.cnt, 0) - (dim1.cnt * dim2.cnt * dim3.cnt)/(dimall.cnt*dimall.cnt) as dev
      FROM (select sn.sessionnumber, sc.sessioncount, ts.timespent
            from (select distinct sessioncount from d3) sc cross join
                 (select distinct timespent from d3) ts cross join
                 (select distinct sessionnumber from d3) sn
           ) allcells left join
           (select sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent, sum(cnt) as cnt
            from d3
            group by sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent
           ) cells
           on allcells.sessioncount = cells.sessioncount and
              allcells.timespent = cells.timespent and
              allcells.sessionnumber = cells.sessionnumber left JOIN
           (SELECT sessionnumber, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY sessionnumber
           ) dim1
           ON allcells.sessionnumber = dim1.sessionnumber left JOIN
            (SELECT sessioncount, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY sessioncount
           ) dim2
           ON allcells.sessioncount = dim2.sessioncount left JOIN
           (SELECT timespent, SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
            GROUP BY timespent
           ) dim3
           ON allcells.timespent = dim3.timespent CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT SUM(cast(cnt as float)) as cnt
            FROM d3
          ) dimall
     ) a
```

Along with its corresponding [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f64/21).

For both the SQL Fiddle versions, I have verified that the sum of the expected values equals the sum of the original counts, which is a good validation of the arithmetic.

Comment: So can you please give me the query according to my sample data i have given please! I have two columns i.e session count and timespent...

Comment: your post also have 3 tables by the way!

Comment: Sir the problem is that the query executes correcly but it gives wrong results and i have tried my best altered it whily trying my lasts can you please give me a query based on my sample data i will be thankful to you its my humble request please please

Comment: @JunaidHassan . . . The revised queries at the end of the answer don't work?  They work in the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @JunaidHassan . . . I don't know how you know the answers are wrong.  They definitely pass the "reasonableness" test, which is that the sum of the expected values matches the sum of the overall values.

Comment: I have the sql tables and I'm applying onto them